# API access using OAuth 2.0 results in "Access token is not valid" error

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I am creating some APIs in PHP using Laravel framework. These APIs will be accessed by clients using my library. I want to secure these APIs using OAuth 2.0. This is what I have so far:

I am using this Laravel package to do OAuth : https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

I have added below to oauth2.php config file:

```
'client_credentials' => array(
'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentials',
'access_token_ttl' => 3600,
),
```

I have below code in my Routes.php:

```
Route::get('oauth/access_token', function()
{
return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
});

Route::get('secure-route', array('before' => 'oauth:scope1,scope2', function(){
return "oauth secured route";
}));
```

When I access first route using below URL:

http://example.com/crm/public/index.php/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1&client_secret=acadgildsecret&state=123456789&scope=scope1

I get below response:

```
{
access_token: "VQzbxeOYCaBvOKkAasEu6w3i3XLBSZgghnc8q8df",
token_type: "bearer",
expires: 1409681582,
expires_in: 3600
}
```

Then I use this access token to access my API using below URL:

http://example.com/crm/public/index.php/secure-route?access_token=%20%27VQzbxeOYCaBvOKkAasEu6w3i3XLBSZgghnc8q8df%27

At this point I get an Unauthorized error:

```
{
status: 401,
error: "unauthorized",
error_message: "Access token is not valid"
}
```

Comment: Your actually sending `access_token= 'VQzbxeOYCaBvOKkAasEu6w3i3XLBSZgghnc8q8df'` check how your creating the query.

Comment: Isn't that's how we are supposed to call APIs once we get access token ? I am following this:
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel#accessing-the-api

Comment: No `access_token=VQzbxeOYCaBvOKkAasEu6w3i3XLBSZgghnc8q8df` would be correct, check the percent encoded extras